# Why can $\frac{2x^3-3x^2+2x-4}{x^2+4}$ be expressed as $2x-3 +\frac{-6x+8}{x^2+4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

Let's say we have an improper function:

$$P(x) = \frac{2x^3-3x^2+2x-4}{x^2+4}$$

If we do long division why does the polynomial can be expressed as "quotient + reminder/divisor"

$$P(x) =2x-3 +\frac{-6x+8}{x^2+4}$$

this does not look like Euclid's division algorithm

Comment: Just write the Euclidean division of the numerator by the denominator.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe can you elaborate more?

Comment: Are you asking how to perform polynomial long division?

Comment: @MPW euclid is P = divisor*quoatient+ reminder but why the form "quotient + reminder/divisor"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ with $f,g\in k[x]$ for some field $k$. By Euclidean division we have that there exist $q, r\in k[x]$ such that $$f(x) = q(x)g(x)+r(x),\ \deg r < \deg g \text{ or } r = 0.$$
Dividing by $g$ we get $$P(x) = q(x) + \frac{r(x)}{g(x)},\ \deg r < \deg g \text{ or } r = 0.$$

Note that this works the same as in case of numbers. For example, $11 = 2\cdot 5 + 1$, so $\frac{11}5 = 2 + \frac 15$.